# My Vscode tab filename text is changing colors. How do I disable that?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just updated to VSCode 1.55.0. Now when I have files open in editor tabs, sometimes the file text is in green, sometimes it is in orange, or just plain white. I don't care what these colors are trying to tell me (I assume it is something version control related).

How do I disable this?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: There's a screenshot at the linked answer.